# Error al exportar excel de una vista blade en laravel usando maatwebsite/excel

Tags: mysql, laravel, excel, laravel-blade, blade

Estoy intentado exportar un registro especifico de una vista blade con el paquete maatwebsite/excel. Le paso un parametro que es el ID del registro pero me sale el sgte error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la documentacion del paquete: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/from-view.html

este es el boton donde llama el controlador para exportar el archivo

```
 <a href="{{URL::action('AbonoController@exportAbono',$cue->idcuenta)}}">
                            <button class="btn btn-default">
                                Excel
                            </button></a>
```

Esta es la clase que genere para utilizar el paquete `ExcelExport.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;

class ExcelExport implements FromView 
{

    private $id;

    public function __construct($abonos=null)
    {
        $this->id = $abonos;
    }

    public function view(): view{

        $abonos = $this->id;
        return view("excel.abonoE", compact("abonos"));


    }
}
```

En el controlador  `AbonoController.php` coloque el metodo para exportar.

```
 public function exportAbono($id)
    {

        $abonos = DB::table('abonos as a')
            ->select('a.idabono', 'a.fecha', 'a.observacion', 'a.saldo_abono', 'a.cantidad', 'a.no_cuota', 'c.cliente_id', 'p.idpersona',
                DB::raw('concat(p.nombres," ",p.apellidos) as cliente'))
            ->join('cuentas as c', 'a.cuenta_id', '=', 'c.idcuenta')
            ->join('personas as p', 'c.cliente_id', '=', 'p.idpersona')
            ->where('a.cuenta_id', '=', $id)
            ->orderBy('idabono', 'DESC')
            ->get();

        return Excel::download(new ExcelExport($abonos), "abonos.xlsx");

    }
```

la vista que quiero exportar en formato excel `abonoE.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section ('contenido')

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <h3>
            Listado de Abonos
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" id="grid">
                <thead style="background-color: #9EDFF5">

                    <th>
                        Cliente
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Observacion
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Fecha
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        No Cuota
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Cantidad
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Saldo
                    </th>
                </thead>
                <!--Bucle que recorre todas las abonos-->
                @foreach ($abonos as $abo)
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{$abo->cliente}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{$abo->observacion}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{$abo->fecha}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{$abo->no_cuota}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{$abo->cantidad}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{$abo->saldo_abono}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

por ultimo la ruta `web.php`

```
Route::get('exportar/abonos{id}', 'AbonoController@exportAbono');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No deberías de estar utilizando
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section ('contenido')

lo que espera la vista para la exportación es simplemente una tabla en html, sin estilos:

```
<table>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Cliente</th>
                        <th>Observacion</th>
                        <th>Fecha</th>
                        <th>No Cuota</th>
                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                        <th>Saldo</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach ($abonos as $abo)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$abo->cliente}}</td>
                            <td>{{$abo->observacion}}</td>
                            <td>{{$abo->fecha}}</td>
                            <td>{{$abo->no_cuota}}</td>
                            <td>{{$abo->cantidad}}</td>
                            <td>{{$abo->saldo_abono}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```